# Pod storyboard issue in swift 3

Tags: cocoapods

I did a pod which contains a storyboard, so when some one doing pod install and importing the pod, the storyboard is not loaded into copy bundle resources(Build Phase). so he needs to go there and need to add it manually. Is there anyway it can be loaded directly

Comment: What's your podspec?

Comment: # check here:https://github.com/karthikAdaptavant/FullFeedback-ios